# Primes in modular arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression

Fix a prime $p$.

I want to get $k<p$ primes $p_1<\dots<p_k$ such that at every $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ we have
$$p_i\equiv (2i+1+c)\bmod p$$ where $c$ is fixed and $2k+1+c<p$ holds.

1. For a given $p$ what is the maximum $k$ I can get?
2. For a given $p$ and given $k$ what is the minimum $p_1$ and $p_k$ that can achieve this?
3. How small can $\prod_{i=1}^kp_i$ be?
4. What are the smallest ratios $\frac{p_1}{p}$ and $\frac{p_k}{p}$?

Comment: Siefel-Walfisz estimate give a partial answer to 2 and 3. $\forall \epsilon>0$, $p_1,p_k$ can choose moroally $O((\log p)^{1+\epsilon})$, and $\Pi_{i=1}^k p_i$ can choose moroally $O((\log p)^{(p-c-1)(1+\epsilon)})$

Comment: Sorry this is not true, use Siefel-Walfisz we can only get a estimate $\forall \epsilon>0$, $p_1,p_k$ can choosed $O(e^{p^{\epsilon}})$, and $\Pi_{i=1}^kp_i$ can be choosed $O(e^{p^{\epsilon}(p-c-1)})$. and the best thing we can expect for 2 and 3 maybe is the unprove(and without tool to attack it now) bound in the previous comment.

Comment: @katago Could you stil lprovide a detailed answer?

Comment: @katago I made the remainders all odd. I think this will shrink the size of $p_k$ or else we have to alternate between odd and even multiples of $p$ for $p_i$ as $i$ increases.

Comment: from wiki, the statement of Siefel-Walfisz theorem is, Define
$$
\psi(x ; q, a)=\sum_{n \leq x \atop n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \Lambda(n)
$$
where $\Lambda$ denotes the von Mangoldt function, and let $\varphi$ denote Euler's totient function.
Then the theorem states that given any real number $N$ there exists a positive constant $C_{N}$ depending only on $N$ such that
$$
\psi(x ; q, a)=\frac{x}{\varphi(q)}+O\left(x \exp \left(-C_{N}(\log x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right)
$$
whenever $(a, q)=1$ and
$$
q \leq(\log x)^{N}
$$

Comment: a remark is, the constant $C_{N}$ is not effectively computable because Siegel's theorem is ineffective.
From the theorem we can deduce the following bound regarding the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions: If, for $(a, q)=1,$ by $\pi(x ; q, a)$ we denote the number of primes less than or equal to $x$ which are congruent to $a \bmod q$, then
$$
\pi(x ; q, a)=\frac{\operatorname{Li}(x)}{\varphi(q)}+O\left(x \exp \left(-\frac{C_{N}}{2}(\log x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right)
$$
where $N, a, q, C_{N}$ and $\varphi$ are as in the theorem, and Li denotes the logarithmic integral.

Comment: it is esay the gain the previous estimat from the remark.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $c\geq 0$, the answer to 1 is that there is no bound for $k$ besides the one stated in the question: $2k+1+c<p$. That is, the maximum $k$ is given by $\lfloor \frac{p-c}{2}\rfloor$.

Indeed, since $0<2+1+c<p$ and thus $\gcd(2+1+c,p)=1$, by [Dirichlet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), there exists prime $p_1$ satisfying
$$p_1\equiv 2+1+c\pmod{p}.$$
Then, again by Dirichlet theorem, there exists $p_2>p_1$ such that
$$p_2\equiv 4+1+c\pmod{p}.$$
And so on.